# ServiceNow - getting the display name from assignedto field

Tags: c#, .net, servicenow

I am getting the ***assignedto*** field as `d7ec53d80f0a650000af0bcce1050ea2`. Instead, I need to get the user `display name`. How to get the `display name` for ***assignedto*** in [ServiceNow - Release Management](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=ITIL_Release_Management#gsc.tab=0)

```
Web Reference Url = https://*****.service-now.com/rm_story.do?WSDL
```

Code:

```
            var url = "https://*****.service-now.com/rm_story.do?SOAP";
            var userName = *****;
            var password = *****;

            var proxy = new ServiceNow_rm_story
            {
                Url = url,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password)
            };

            try
            {
                var objRecord = new Namespace.WebReference.getRecords
                {
                    // filters..
                };

                var recordResults = proxy.getRecords(objRecord);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

In `recordResults` from the code above, I am able to `enumerate` and get the `assignedto` field, but the `value` is displaying in ( some *guid or unknown* format - example - `d7ec53d80f0a650000af0bcce1050ea2`) pattern. I need to get the `display name`.

How to get the `display name` for ***assignedto*** field ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AssignedTo is a reference field, and the d7ec53d80f0a650000af0bcce1050ea2 value you are seeing is the sys_id (uuid) of the user the rm_story is assigned to. Instead you want the display value which you can get by adding 'displayvalue=true' to your SOAP request URL. You can also specify 'displayvalue=all' to have both the sys_id and the display value returned in the soap response. Check out the ServiceNow SOAP Web Service docs ([link](http://wiki.servicenow.com/?title=Direct_Web_Services#Return_Display_Value_for_Reference_Variables)) for additional info and sample. Hope that helps.

If using REST instead of SOAP is an option I would recommend checking out ServiceNow [REST Table API](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Table_API#gsc.tab=0) and using the [REST API Explorer](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=REST_API_Explorer#gsc.tab=0) to help you build your HTTP Requests and easily specify parameters like display value.

[REST API Explorer](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=REST_API_Explorer#gsc.tab=0)
[REST Table API](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Table_API#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: Thank You very much. Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://XXXXX.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/incident?sysparm_display_value=true
```

The URL will be replaced by the actual display name for REST API